# How to insert Dot on Each character

Tags: c#, string

when a user enter a name Like USA  its should be changed to U.S.A., how can I write

```
str hell0 = "USA"
```

It should be saved in database like `U.S.A`

Comment: Is it only for string "USA"?

Comment: no brother I jut gave when customer enter any Like John,Jim,Pill....any name  but server stores j.I.M

Comment: so if cıstomer enters `John,Jim,Pill` then it should be inserted like `J.J.P`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
string inputStr = "USA";
string outputStr = String.Join(".",inputStr.ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(outputStr);
```

Working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pFMxBv)

Comment: @MdDastageerJob: How that is related to this question? It seems like another question, please ask it as a different one

Answer (score 2):

In order to change abbreviations *within the text*, you can try using *Linq*:

```
string source = 
  @"when a client insert a Name Like UAS its should be take as U.S.A  how can I wrote";

string result = string.Concat(Enumerable
  .Range(0, source.Length)
  .Select(index => index > 0 && 
                   char.IsUpper(source[index - 1]) && 
                   char.IsUpper(source[index])
    ? "." + source[index].ToString()
    : source[index].ToString())
  .ToArray());
```

Test

```
Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome

```
when a client insert a Name Like U.A.S its should be take as U.S.A  how can I wrote
```

*Regular expressions* is an alternative (see un-lucky's answer below):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(
  source, "[A-Z]{2,}", 
  match => string.Join(".", match.Value.ToArray())); // taken from un-lucky's answer
```